# CultureInfo.ClearCachedData is not working properly in .net 4.6 and older for WPF only

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cultureinfo, .net-4.6

Consider the following simple WPF application:

XAML (MainWindow):

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Old"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="New"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Old.Text = $"Old culture name {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}";
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
                New.Text = $"New culture name {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}";
            };
        }
```

Each time the user changes their regional settings it will print to Old TextBlock the old culture's name and, after calling `ClearCachedData`, the new culture's name will be set on New TextBlock. This is the window where I change these settings in Clock and Region section within Control Panel:

[image]

Now, if you build targeting 4.5.2 or less, it will work as expected and you will receive, after actually changing the setting, an output similar to this:

[image]

Now, build targeting 4.6 or later versions, you get something like this:

[image]

If you are targeting 4.6 or later, no matter how many times you change the number format region, no matter how many times you call `ClearCachedData`, CurrentCulture will not change...

But wait! Things get weirder... If you put above code into a Console App (using Console.WriteLine instead of course), it works not depending in which framework you chose (4.5.2, 4.6, anything..), strange isn't it? That is why I wrote "WPF only" in the title.. but I do not know for sure if this happens in any other platform other than WPF

There is still another crazy thing in this tale, since I have been playing around with this issue since yesterday, I found a trikcy way to make WPF or Console apps, targeting 4.5.2 or below, working wrong, just as the one targeting 4.6 and older. Simply setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` to anything different from null will break things apart.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Old.Text = $"Old culture name {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}";
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
        New.Text = $"New culture name {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}";
    };
}
```

The above code will behave as if it were targeting 4.6. So, what I thought was that WPF targeting 4.6 was setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` in some way, but after testing this theory I am really stuck, because it is null by default, event in 4.6 and older...

So, is this a bug in WPF and/or .NET 4.6? I have not been able to find this breaking change reported.

Please, anything that shed some light on this will be appreciated. Also, if this is a bug and anyone know where could I report it, please tell me.

Note: I tag this question with C# as it is the language I am using, although I consider this issue is language independent.

Comment: Well, big big changes in .NET 4.6.  It fixes an [old problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2#Async) with culture not flowing from one thread to another.  If its implementation causes this problem, not so obvious to me that it does, then consider to use the [AppContextSwitchOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element) in the app.config file to opt out.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for your help. I performed the test by setting to true `Switch.System.Globalization.NoAsyncCurrentCulture`, I validate that the switch was enabled by calling `AppContext.TryGetSwitch`. Unfortunately I had no success...

Comment: Btw.. I do not think it is directly related with .net 4.6 since it is working in a Console application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those visitors from the future and beyond who may will be having the same issue. I found a sort of workaround:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Old.Text = $"Old culture name {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}";
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new Thread(() => { }).CurrentCulture;
            New.Text = $"New culture name {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}";
        };
    }
```

The above code will work in both building options: 4.5.2 and earlier, or 4.6 and later. Notice that the call to `ClearCachedData` is still a must. We create a new thread instance and we manually update our CurrentCulture to that of the new thread.

Happy coding!